# Can I combine two $scope variables and have these display in a disable <input> box

Tags: angularjs

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="w25p">
    <span>PId</span>
    <input class="w50p"
           disabled="disabled"
           data-ng-model="modal.data.problemId" />
</div>
<div class="w25p">
    <span>QId</span>
    <input class="w50p"
           disabled="disabled"
           data-ng-model="modal.data.questionId" />
</div>
```

These are read-only fields and I wanted to combine them. So I coded this:

```
<div class="w25p">
    <span>PId : QId</span>
    <input class="w50p"
           disabled="disabled"
           data-ng-bind="{{ modal.data.problemId + ' + ' + modal.data.questionid }}" />
</div>
```

However it seems not to work. How could I combine problemId and questionId so they 
both appear in the  box. Note that I was using an input to make everything
match up with all the other  boxes on my pages. If possible I would like to do this in the view without code in the controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the **value** attribute instead:

```
<input value="{{ modal.data.problemId + ' + ' + modal.data.questionid }}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

According to **[the docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angBind)**:

> The ngBind attribute tells Angular to replace the text content of the specified HTML element with the value of a given expression

---

**But**, the `<input>` element has a value but not text content, thus `ng-bind` has no effect.
You can set the `value` attribute directly:

```
<input class="w50p" disabled="disabled"
       value="{{modal.data.problemId}} - {{modal.data.questionId}}" />
```

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/3q272/)**.